# From string to binary file

Tags: c, file

I have a problem, I need to write bits in a text file in C.
I want to save a string whose size is 5 bytes,

```
char code[] = "0110";
```

In a file bit by bit, so that the final file size be only 4 bits.

```
Input:  size(file) = 5 bytes.
Output: size(file) = 4 bits.
```

My question is: is there a function ( eg fwrite() ) in C that can do this ?

Comment: I doubt any filesystem allows sizes of bits. You are likely gonna have overhead. Can you provide more perspective into why you are doing this? You could convert it into an `int` or a `char` and then write it into the file.

Comment: These teachers are getting more imaginative on their homework questions!

Comment: stackoverflow is a Q&A site. What's your question?

Comment: @ouah - I guess the question is "I cannot be arsed to do my homework, can you do it for me"

Comment: Not only is it doubtful that any filesystem would let you write less than a byte, the vast majority use an entire block (such as 4 kB) for any file, no matter how small.

Comment: I am implementing the algorithm Huffman, and I need to save the codeword (0012245) to a file, but this only save bit by bit.

Comment: but it seems the only way is to convert it to an integer and then retrieve it = /, I thought there was a function in C that would do that.

Comment: "I am implementing the algorithm Huffman" -- You should have said so in the first place. But your question would still be closed because you haven't done any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert your string that represent a binary number into a char and then write your byte in the file.

You will have some overhead since you can't write only 4 bits.

```
  char *in = "0110";
  char out = 0;

  int i = 0;
  while (in[i] != '\0') {
    out = out * 2 + in[i] - '0';
    i++;
  }

  // Write out in your file.
```

Comment: Thank so much, seems that this is the only solution :).

Comment: @user2536844 I edited since you explained that was to implement Huffman, this issue was not directly the homework assignment :).

Answer (score 1):

The C APIs will (reasonably) not let you write 4 bits to a file.
I also don't think there is a file system out there which will keep record of content as half bytes!
This is just to say that what you want to do is to interpret a string of `1`s and `0`s as a bunch of bits in a byte.

In order to do so, you have to write bits.
This is usually achieved with bitwise operators.

So, for example, if you have a "stream" of 8 bytes `10011100`, you can pack a byte with the following code:

```
char *sb = "10011100";
unsigned char next = 0;  // Next bit to process
unsigned char pos = 0;   // Position of next bit
unsigned char byte = 0;  // Where to store the result
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if ((*sb) == '1') {
        next = 0x01;
    }
    else {
        next = 0x00;
    }
    byte |= next << pos;
    pos++;
}
```

This code will read each character out of the string and push a `1` or a `0` (not even necessary as the initial value is `0x00`, but efficiency is not a concern here) into `byte` by using a bitwise `OR` operator.

This is a very simple example, you have to figure out corner cases (what if the input string  has only 5 bytes), bit ordering issues (where to put those 5 bits, at the beginning or at the end of the byte? And what beginning and end means?), etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a broader vision of the problem.